# Payment integration using Mula Payment Gateway

Tags: php

I want to integrate "Mula payment gateway" with my application.

Application scenario:

1) Product selection from the Store page (Add to cart)

2) Now on the cart page, there is "Checkout" functionality

3) On the Checkout page, I am fetching Customer information

4) The amount is payable via Credit Card so that I was fetching Credit Card information

After performing the above operation, I have integrate "Mula payment gateway" with my application. For this I am following below API(s) :

Authentication : https://beep2.cellulant.com:9001/CheckoutV2/checkoutPublicAPI/oauth/token

Fetch Payment Options: https://beep2.cellulant.com:9001/CheckoutV2/checkoutPublicAPI/api/payment/options/YOUR_CLIENT_CODE?countryCode=YOUR_COUNTRY_CODE&languageCode=YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE

Initiate Transaction : https://beep2.cellulant.com:9001/CheckoutV2/checkoutPublicAPI/api/transaction

Fetch Transaction Payment Details : https://beep2.cellulant.com:9001/CheckoutV2/checkoutPublicAPI/api/transaction/payment-details

While checking API response using https://beep2.cellulant.com:9211/docs/api URL,i Could not able to find How to authenticate Credit Card information which customer is provided during checkout process? Because I had test all below API(s), I could not find authentication process of Credit Card.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I want to integrate this api with one of my project.

Comment: I didn't find any developer document for integration. But specially for this payment gateway you need to communicate with the developer support team. Because this payment gateway not like stripe or PayPal payment gateway which provides you developer document for smooth integration.